# Using ul or with div with CSS property flex for responsive site

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

There is a choice between using `u`l and `div` elements when it comes to responsive design. This question is specifically about the navigation bar.

I used `ul` --following many other developers-- and then discovered that for certain navigation behaviors, it's much easier to use `display: flex` property, like so:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div><a href="#">LOGIN</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">REGISTER</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">BASKET</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
    font: bold 1.2em/45px "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: black;
}

.navbar a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font: bold 1.2em/45px "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
}
```

Is there a downside to using this method?

Comment: No. Only  one thing is `display:flex` supports in only modern browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are really no downsides to either method.

If you are thinking about the stuff you can do with CSS or JavaScript, using `<ul>` or `<div>` elements will make no difference.

The only real issue is browser support. If you check out [this page](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), you will see that `display: flex` is not supported in IE9 or earlier. It is also still not fully supported in IE, because of a large amount of bugs present.

Here is a quote (from the page) of the known issues with Flexboxes:

> - IE 11 does not vertically align items correctly when min-height is used
> - IE 11 incorrectly focuses a child element if the parent uses display:flex and has a tabindex set
> - In IE 10, setting -ms-flex-flow: row wrap will not wrap unless display: inline-block is set on child elements.
> - IE11 does not wrap long paragraphs of text
> - IE11 will not apply flexbox on pseudo-elements.
> - Firefox does not support Flexbox in button elements
> - In Chrome and Safari, the height of (non flex) children are not recognized in percentages. However Firefox and IE recognize and scale
>     the children based on percentage heights.
> - In IE10 the default value for flex is 0 0 auto rather than 0 1 auto as defined in the latest spec.
> - In IE10 and IE11, containers with display: flex and flex-direction: column will not properly calculate their flexed
>     childrens' sizes if the container has min-height but no explicit
>     height property.

As you can see, most of the issues are with IE10 and IE11.

Since you are not using buttons, the Firefox issue is not important. The only thing that may concern you in other browsers is the Chrome and Safari bug, on sizes set in percentages.

So, to conclude, using `<ul>` is probably your safest bet. However, if you are not concerned about browser support, use `display: flex` if you want.

Also, check out [Flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs). It contains workarounds for many Flexbox issues

Answer (score 0):

Downside would be that it won't work on internet explorer and some mobile browsers... You should check your code with bootstrap.css navbar as it too is responsive